# How can Logstash find out the name of the host where a log came from?

Tags: logging, dns, logstash, monitoring, elastic-stack

This sounds like it should be easy--I'm sure I'm not the first to have this problem. So I must be missing something obvious.

I'm setting up a Logstash instance to collect logs from several applications, each running on a different Amazon EC2 host.

I want Logstash to know the name of the host where each log message came from, in order to trigger certain behavior (such as using "grok" to parse fields that are present only in a certain application's log, or sending email alerts only for a certain application). I can't use the actual text of log messages for this because the log format of each one is different.

I thought I could use the built-in "host" field, but that turns out to be just an IP address. It's possible to do a reverse DNS lookup each time a log message is received, like

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "hostname" => "%{host}" }
    }
    dns {
        action => "replace"
            reverse => [ "hostname" ]
            add_tag => [ "dns_lookup" ]
    }

    if "myapplication" in [hostname] {
            # do something
    }
}
```

but that gives one of Amazon's IP address-based names like "ip-10-1-1-23.ec2.internal".

All I want is for Logstash to see the same name shown by the "hostname" command. Is that possible? Or could I somehow make the log-sending applications explicitly add their hostname to the data they send?

If it's relevant, the applications send their logs using the Logstash TCP protocol (via [python-logstash](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash)) but could they just as easily use syslog, or any other protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash cannot find the hostname of a remote machine, the way to have this information in your logs is to add it at the host before sending the logs to logstash.

Filebeat, a log shipping tool for taking log files and sending them to Logstash, adds the information to events before sending them, so if your applications log to a file I suggest checking out Filebeat.

Another option would be to customize your logs to include the hostname somewhere along your shipping process yourself.

Either way the hostname should be added to the log event before its sent to logstash.

Comment: What's the advantage of Filebeat over running a separate Logstash instance on each host (all sending logs to the same Elasticsearch instance)?

Comment: do all your processing in one place in one Logstash, and Filebeat is a tiny Go application, not a huge JVM app competing with your application for resources